# Does "multi_gpu_model" support "Sequential"?

Tags: python, keras, gpu, sequential, multi-gpu

I implemented "keras.utils.training_utils.multi_gpu_model" function on "keras.models.Sequential" model. But it wasn't working. Oddly Xception model(keras.applications.Xception) is working properly. Error message is as below.

```
File "cifar10_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    multi_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=3)
  File "/.../my-env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/training_utils.py", line 155, in multi_gpu_model
    for i in range(len(model.outputs)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Here is my code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Convolution2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.utils.training_utils import multi_gpu_model
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import tensorflow as tf


def cnn_model1():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    return model


(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
model = cnn_model1()
multi_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=3)
multi_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
multi_model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), nb_epoch=3, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
```

FYI I'm using tensorflow-gpu-1.9.0, Keras-2.2.0, python-3.5.2 and 4 Quadro M6000 24GB GPU is on my computer.

Can anyone give me an advice?

Comment: seing as model.outputs is None, it does not seem to me that it works on sequential models. Try to recreate the model using functional API instead.